# What's wrong with mysqli when connecting to database?

Tags: php, html

This is my connect.php :

```
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "xxxxxxxx";
$mysql_database = "marrybrown_clean";
$bd = mysqli_connect ($mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die ('Could not connect database!');
mysqli_select_db ($mysql_database, $bd) or die (" Could not select database!");
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
**Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\marrybrown_clean\connect.php on line 7
Could not select database!**
```

How to fix it?

Comment: first parameter is your connection string then your database name change `mysqli_select_db ($mysql_database, $bd)` to `mysqli_select_db ($bd,$mysql_database)`

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
mysqli_select_db ($mysql_database, $bd)
```

should be

```
mysqli_select_db ($bd, $mysql_database)
```

The link (`$bd`) comes first in the `mysqli` functions.

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_select_db requires first parameter to be mysqli_connect(); so it should be as follow.

```
mysqli_select_db ($bd, $mysql_database)
```

Comment: Correct but little late!!

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in `mysqli_selct_db` is the connection parameter, the only thing you did wrong is you have **interchanged the variables**.

*So this line :*

```
mysqli_select_db ($mysql_database, $bd);
```

*Needs to be **replaced by** :*

```
mysqli_select_db ($bd, $mysql_database);
```

Also you can do something like this :

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect
    ($mysql_hostname,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$mysql_database) 
    or die('Could not connect to database!');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to select the database while connecting:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect
    ($mysql_hostname,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$mysql_database) 
    or die('Could not connect to database!');
```

You can also use the object oriented style:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli
    ($mysql_hostname,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mysqli_select_db ($bd,$mysql_database)
```

Like in http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.select-db.php